# Purpose of templates.json and schemas.json

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2

In normal cases (and in the example website), the Publish Settings in DXA will result in a `[ModuleName].schemas.json` and `[ModuleName].templates.json` inside of "/system/config/" folder, but this only happens if the Schemas and (dynamic) Component Templates are inside the "Modules" Folder. This is hardcoded in the templating solution.

Because I have my Schemas and Templates defined in a different folder (because it's an earlier implementation), I do not have these files. My implementation is working correctly, but I want to make sure that these files are not needed by some (hidden) functionality in DXA. Can someone shed some light on their purpose?

Comment: In earlier versions, we will not be able to render the view-models; since model registration would fail. I honestly have not tested it. Interesting that you found a hardcode on the CM site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DXA Framework itself doesn't use these configuration files, but Module implementation may.

For example, the Core Module's `ContentList` View Model uses it to map a Schema name to ID (used to do a Broker Query).  See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/master/webapp-net/Core/Models/Entity/ContentList.cs

In general, DXA expects that on CM side, all Module-specific Schemas and Templates are in the Module's subtree under the /{Root}/Modules folder.  It then creates Module-specific config files called {Module}.xyz.json